# Realtime priority and realtime priority queueing in Flash with very low latency?

Tags: java, flash, real-time, rtmfp, low-latency

Is it possible to perform realtime priority processing and queueing in Flash at exceptionally low latency levels?  We have some rather large data streams (they are raw audio and probably should be compressed with an efficient compression algorithm that will add extremely little overhead) that need to receive realtime priority on the client host and then transferred with as low of a low latency stream as possible to the receiving end.  Is this possible with Flash to perform realtime extremely low latency connection?

It seems as though I may have to shift gears to Java or even C / C# given these requirements...  But I'm hopeful to discover something that I have as of yet not seen.

Comment: AFAIK, Flash only has one thread and is only used to display information to users. A human can't see flickering of less than 20 ms, so anything faster than this is unlikely to matter. What is this "low of low latency" specifically? Is it 100 ms, 10 ms, 1 ms, 100 us, 10 us?

Comment: It needs to be < 100 ms cumulatively for one transfer across.

Comment: Depending on how much work you have to do per update and how data you need to process I would have expected Flash could achieve this.  In Java I have written trading systems with less than 0.1 ms latency. If you need much less than this then C or C++ is you best option.